# GAE Go Windows - "Cannot run program", "is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, compiler-errors, go, executable

I've been trying to run a GAE Go project I developed on my Mac on my Windows machine with GoClipse after installing and configuring the appropriate SDKs and so forth. When attempting to run the project, I get this error:

> Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program
>   "C:\GoogleAppEngine\dev_appserver.py" (in directory
>   "D:\Golang\workspace\Project\src\pkg"): CreateProcess
>   error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

How can I fix that error in order to run my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the below configuration works on the Mac as it has Python installed by default, Windows requires a different configuration.

On Mac the GoClipse External Tools Configuration would be:

```
Location: /GoogleAppEngine/dev_appserver.py
Working Directory: ${workspace_loc:/Project/src/pkg}
Arguments: .
```

The Windows configuration should look like:

```
Location: C:\Python27\Python.exe
Working Directory:
Arguments: C:\GoogleAppEngine\dev_appserver.py "${workspace_loc:/Project/src/pkg}"
```

Comment: So u found the answer, awesome!

Comment: I'm getting the same error and I tried this. Eclipse terminates at the .py script. What might I be missing?

Comment: @GauravBhor if your workspace path contains spaces, you might need to add quotation marks perhaps. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have spaces. And I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to run .py (Which IMO is a Python file?) wont work directly on windows. You will need to install Python and then pass the above filename to Python  something like (I don't know Python so don't go by exact syntax, you might need to look around)

```
python "C:\GoogleAppEngine\dev_appserver.py
```

The reason it's working on Mac is because Python comes pre-installed on mac as cited [here](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/) But on windows it doesn't. So you can install Python and add the Python's bin folder to path, and then run above script and it should run fine!

Comment: As I'm using GoClipse and trying to do this through External Tools Configuration, trying to type in `python C:\GoogleAppEngine\dev_appserver.py` or any permutation of this an error message of "External tools location does not exist"

Comment: Do you have Python on your Win machine?

Comment: Yes, I installed Python 2.7.3, I can run the .py files from the cmd without a problem.